# Windows 7 VPN - Error 619 slow behavior

Tags: windows-7, vpn, 64-bit

I have problem with windows 7 64bit VPN connection by pptp on mikrotik. I one company have more than 10 computers connecting to VPN. Only three PCs starts showing **error 619** when connecting to VPN. I notised if I try to click to VPN connection that **window of VPN has a slow response** - its not the time of unsuccessful connection when 619 appears. It is slow beahvior of proces when you connecting to VPN. Same behavior is on all three computers. Other computers are OK.

1. I dont change any configuration of VPN.
2. I try other settings on VPN conection on broken PCs.
3. Tryed to update network devices drivers.
4. Yes, I try found solution on internet... and on this site.

Computers are mainly HP Pro Books.

Please, I will be glad of any advice. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Probably not much help, but I've found exactly the same after the last Windows Update. When connecting, typing username and password is very slow, then each phase of the process shows one-by-one (when it used to just zip by, there are some phases I never knew had status boxes, e.g. "All Devices Connected"). When connected, it works just great. I suspect something in the last Windows Update, but not tried to resolve yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem (after some Googling). This is caused by "Microsoft Security Essentials" real time protection.

Go to MSE (should be icon in your task bar) and turn off real time protection. Save. Then connect to your VPN. Then turn the real time protection back on and the VPN carries on quite happily.

Downside is that you need to repeat each time (until MS fix it, I guess).

Comment: Thanks a lot Robbie, I don't even thought that it will be MSE. I uninstall him and everything goes fine.

Comment: Don't uninstall MSE, just untick then tick the real time protection box when needed. But glad it's working for you too.